# Fontawesome icon not showing

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-fontawesome

I'm trying to develop an angular project completely on my mobile device. I tried using fontawesome icon in my project. While using the minus-square icon, it worked without even creating an account.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<button id="remove" class="fa fa-minus-square"></button>
```

Now I'm trying to use temperature icon and weather icon. It seems like I need an account for that, so I did.

```
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2ee7bde2cf.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Day Summary</h3>
<hr>
<i id="weather" class='fas fa-cloud-moon'></i>
<h2>Cloudy</h2>
<i id="temperature" class='fas fa-temperature-high'></i>
```

This doesn't shows icon at all. I tried the same minus-square icon it worked, but this doesn't working.
These icon working at https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?icon=fas_fa-temperature-high&unicon=f769
Completely fine.
Help me.
I'm on mobile device working on Angular.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @MiaKhalifa! I hope you find this community helpful and friendly and feel motivated to ask more questions and to contribute back.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the `2pe7bfe2cy.js` file on your code returns *Access Denied* to me. The w3schools example uses a different URL (to the `a076d05399.js` file):

```
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
```

Updating your code with the 2nd file works on Chrome for macOS:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Day Summary</h3>
<hr>
<i id="weather" class='fas fa-cloud-moon'></i>
<h2>Cloudy</h2>
<i id="temperature" class='fas fa-temperature-high'></i>
```

The `a076d05399.js` file says `"license": "free"`, which includes both icons you mentioned. Perhaps you missed a step on account creation?

---

*Alternative*: considering it works here on this example, this could be a configuration issue. Since you're using Angular, Font Awesome has an [official Angular component](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular). Docs says:

> If you are using Angular, you need the angular-fontawesome package or
> Web Fonts with CSS.

Did you try installing the [angular-fontawesome package](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome)?

Comment: I just change the code to the file that I gave in the above code. I just edit the code now. I hope it wont give access deny now. I even tried using that working code but still no icon showing. As I told already the other minus-square icon is working but these other not working. @Ricardo

Comment: I tried the new `2ee7bde2cf.js` file on both your code snippet and on on the w3schools code snippet and it shows the expected icons.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm working on Angular project and turn out I need to put it in the main html (index.html) file to make it work

Comment: Cool! If this answer helped you solving your issue, you may consider marking it as accepted. Best regards!